# How to search for an NFT asset name?

Tags: nft, native-assets, cardano-db-sync

Let's say, I have created an asset with name 'xyz' and I want to search for all the nfts with this asset name on the chain. How and where do I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

May I ask why you'd want to do this?

It will be much easier for you to store the name of your NFT's in a database somewhere and query that instead of the blockchain. The blockchain is very quick at looking up NFT's under a given policy_id or asset string. Custom metadata? Not so much.